Problem with the Outlook web add-in debugger using the Outlook desktop client
I created a web add-in for Outlook in August 2023. Now, after a year, I wanted to debug it and I can't run it using the desktop client. I get this message:
One or more errors occurred.

Failed to launch debug adapter. Additional information may be available in the output window.

Unable to launch browser: 'The browser process exited with code 0 before connecting to the debug server. Make sure the `runtimeExecutable` is configured correctly and that it can run without errors.'

I use Visual Studio.
I tried reinstalling Visual Studio, reinstalling Outlook. I also cleared Outlook's cache. It didn't help.
Update
When I change the platform from the standard Outlook client to a browser, e.g. Edge, the above error does not appear, but the add-in does not load. Sometimes it will show and sometimes it won't. And sometimes other add-ins, such as OneNote, etc., do not even appear. I also have no way to reach the window with custom Outlook add-ins to check whether the add-in has been added.
Below is the very beginning of the xml manifest, which worked a year ago:
<OfficeApp
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
          xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0"
          xsi:type="MailApp">
    <Id>...</Id>
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <ProviderName>...</ProviderName>
    <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
    <DisplayName DefaultValue="..." />
    <Description DefaultValue="..." />
    <IconUrl DefaultValue="..." />
    <SupportUrl DefaultValue="http://www.contoso.com" />
    <AppDomains>
        <AppDomain>outlook.live.com</AppDomain>
        <AppDomain>https://localhost:44374/</AppDomain>
        <AppDomain>http://localhost:59790/</AppDomain>
    </AppDomains>
    <Hosts>
        <Host Name="Mailbox" />
    </Hosts>
    <Requirements>
        <Sets>
            <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
        </Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <FormSettings>
        <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
            <DesktopSettings>
                <SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/" />
                <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
            </DesktopSettings>
        </Form>
    </FormSettings>
    <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
    <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
        <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read" />
    </Rule>
    <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
        <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
            <Requirements>
                <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
                    <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
                </bt:Sets>
            </Requirements>
            <Hosts>
                <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
                    <DesktopFormFactor>
                        <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />
                        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">

Can I access the manifest after the last Outlook update? This cannot be found on the Internet.

Debugging with Outlook classic on windows is a very tough experience. As you mentioned, the add-in can experience an error that seems to take down the entire add-in framework and cause other add-ins to not show up or run. On top of this, exceptions can be trapped so there's no indication of what's gone wrong.
The approach I've taken to get it working is start with the web because you can inspect/debug the scripts in the dev console. I also write them in typescript and bundle with webpack and target IE 11 so that the same script can be used for web and Outlook classic.
If you do choose to use the approach below do know that you'll have to experiment with the webpack config for development. I believe it's injecting certain webpack code into the file that still causes the script to fail in Outlook classic at debug time, but it does work in release mode.
Here's the webpack rule I use for my smart alerts
  entry: {
  polyfill: ["core-js/stable", "regenerator-runtime/runtime"],
  vendor: ["react", "react-dom", "core-js", "@fluentui/react-components", "@fluentui/react-icons"],
  taskpane: ["./src/taskpane/index.tsx", "./src/taskpane/taskpane.html"],
  "smart-alerts/autorun-shared": [
    "core-js/stable",
    "regenerator-runtime/runtime",
    "./src/smart-alerts/autorun-shared.ts",
  ], // Include polyfills
},
//...
 {
      test: /\.(ts|js)$/,
      include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src/smart-alerts")],
      use: {
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
          presets: [
            [
              "@babel/preset-env",
              {
                targets: {
                  ie: "11",
                },
                useBuiltIns: "entry",
                corejs: "3",
              },
            ],
            "@babel/preset-typescript",
          ],
        },
      },
      exclude: /node_modules/,
    },

